# Ambiguous column name Error in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two Queries.
1st one is:

```
SELECT hardware, SUM(Quantity) FROM request_1v2 where date between "2016-03-12" AND "2016-03-14" group by hardware
```

Output of 1st Query is

[image]

2nd Query is:

```
SELECT hardware, SUM(Quantity) FROM request_1v2 where date between "2016-03-12" AND "2016-03-12" group by hardware
```

Output of 2nd Query is:

[image]

Actually I am plotting a graph So I need to merge these two queries into a single one. The solution I got is :

```
SELECT t1.hardware, SUM(t1.Quantity), SUM(t2.Quantity) 
FROM request_1v2 AS t1,request_1v2 AS t2 
WHERE t1.date between "2016-03-12" and "2016-03-14" AND t2.date between "2016-03-12" and "2016-03-12" 
GROUP BY t1.hardware
```

Output of Solution Query:

[image]

This is wrong !

Actual Output that I need will be:-

[image]

I don't know how to do it. Can anyone help me.?
Someone suggested me to write your query as:-

```
SELECT hardware, SUM(t1.Quantity), SUM(t2.Quantity) 
FROM request_1v2 AS t1,request_1v2 AS t2 
WHERE t1.date between "2016-03-12" and "2016-03-14" AND t2.date between "2016-03-12" and "2016-03-12" 
GROUP BY hardware
```

But it gives error "**ambiguous column name: hardware**"

Please help me and write the Query as your answer Thanks.

If you need Table Structure Here it is:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a CASE,thing is your dates overlap,you might want to change them.Your third query creates a cartesian JOIN since you dont have a JOIN condition.

```
SELECT hardware, 
SUM(CASE WHEN date between "2016-03-12" AND "2016-03-14" THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END),
SUM(CASE WHEN date between "2016-03-12" AND "2016-03-12" THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END)
 FROM request_1v2 
group by hardware
```

Comment: Thank you Sir ! you are genius :) Respect